# Detect and alarm when app starts installing

Tags: android, installation, detect

Is there any way to detect when an application begins installing? More specifically, when the  system is running the `packageinstall.apk` - Can I capture this moment?

I want to alarm user before apk is installed. I have tried the `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` but it does not work. (`ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` is not what I want either.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. The best you could do is check after the app has been installed whether or not you want it on there and act accordingly.